# Provided scope not working in eclipse

Tags: gradle

Gradle 2.2.1

I am trying to include dependencies into a jar file that I will ship to other users.  I want them to provide their own versions of some dependencies and am trying to emulate the `provided` scope from maven.

I have followed the tutorial [here](http://blog.codeaholics.org/2012/emulating-mavens-provided-scope-in-gradle/).  I am able to successfully build the project from the command line (while still getting classes not found errors in eclipse) until the eclipse integration part.  From the post he says to add `eclipse.classpath.plusConfigurations += configurations.provided` but I am getting `Could not find property 'provided' on configuration container`

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

// this causes the error
//eclipse.classpath.plusConfigurations += configurations.provided

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': '...',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'

    //Jackson
    provided 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.2'
    provided 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.2'
    provided 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.2'
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.

```
eclipse.classpath.plusConfigurations += configurations.provided
```

Should be an array

```
eclipse.classpath.plusConfigurations += [configurations.provided]
```

Comment: This is brilliant, worked for me as well. Thank you.